# PHP nusoap webservice security

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

I am writing soap server and soap client in php. For Authentication of soap services , i  want to use  "usernametoken" for security. Can anyone send me the example applied in server and client using nusoap.

I am using nusoap to write the soap services.

Thanks & Regards,
neetha

Answer (score 9):

SERVER Side:

```
function doAuthenticate(){    
if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) and isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) )
          {
           //here I am hardcoding. You can connect to your DB for user authentication.    

           if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']=="abhishek" and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']="123456" )
                return true;
           else
               return  false;                   

           }
}
```

Call this doAuthenticate function for every operation in server.If it is returning true then only allow the client/user to communicate.

CLIENT side

```
// includes nusoap class
require_once('../lib/nusoap.php');

// Create object
$client = new nusoap_client('<wsdl path>?wsdl', true);
//Setting credentials for Authentication 
$client->setCredentials("abhishek","123456","basic");
..
```

Comment: Hi Neetha please give a response to let me know whether my reply was helpful or not.

Comment: so this is just basic security, sent as plain text?

Comment: Hi abhishek, how the doAuthenticate() function is referred on server side? do we invoke the function on client side?

Comment: Hi its works fine...! please let me know about "digest" and "RELAM" authentications.